# Can't properly serialize POJO with Iterable fields using Gson

Tags: java, json, gson, guava, java-6

Here is my POJO I am trying to serialize:

```
public class Bar {
    private final Foo foo;

    private final Iterable<String> list;

    private final Iterable<Map<String, String>> listOfMaps;
}
```

Here is how I'm calling it

```
Bar bar = new Bar();
Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.field1 = "val1";
foo.field2 = "val2";
bar.foo = foo;
bar.list = ImmutableList.<String>of("fooList");
bar.listOfMaps = ImmutableList.<Map<String,String>>of(
                    ImmutableMap.<String,String>of("key", "val")
                );
new Gson().toJson(bar);
```

Here is the result

```
{"foo":{"field1":"val1","field2":"val2"},"list":{},"listOfMaps":{}}
```

As you can see, the POJO serializes fine, but the iterable (instance of guava collections) doesn't serialize to JSON properly. When I serialize the fields on their own, they show up fine, but it won't properly serialize when they are fields of `Bar`

Example:

```
new Gson().toJson(bar.list);

["fooList"]
```

Comment: since your Bar's fields are final, why you can set value after created?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an old issue for Gson and this is how it was initially designed.
I have some assumptions why it might be designed like that, but I think my assumptions are weak (`Iterable` is just too base type to get a particular implementation by default?; it may intersect with `Collection` and `List`?; what if `Iterable` returns an infinite iterator?).
You can track down the `Iterable` support issue through this pull request: https://github.com/google/gson/pull/854 .

First of all, why Gson behaves differently for both cases you mentioned (`.toJson(bar)` and `.toJson(bar.list)`).
For the first case, Gson scans your `bar` object and it retrieves type information directly from the fields using reflection, and this is where it gets `Iterable`.
For the second case, Gson does not have *declaration type* information therefore it just takes the actual class (not type!) using `.getClass()` losing type parameterization (strings fit this test cast just perfect), `Collection` in this case that has Gson support out of box.
Note that the latter can also be reproduced with `gson.toJson(..., new TypeToken<Iterable<String>>() {}.getType(), System.out)` suggesting the given object *type* (not class!) explicitly.

However, you can add `Iterable` support yourself, but I'm not sure if the implementation below requires more work:

```java
final class IterableMyTypeAdapterFactory
        implements TypeAdapterFactory {

    private static final TypeAdapterFactory iterableTypeAdapterFactory = new IterableMyTypeAdapterFactory();

    private IterableMyTypeAdapterFactory() {
    }

    // It's an effective singleton but we do not reveal it
    static TypeAdapterFactory getIterableMyTypeAdapterFactory() {
        return iterableTypeAdapterFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(final Gson gson, final TypeToken<T> typeToken) {
        // Must be an iterable, subclasses should be picked up by built-in type adapters
        if ( !Iterable.class.isAssignableFrom(typeToken.getRawType()) || Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(typeToken.getRawType()) ) {
            // Tell Gson to pick up on its own
            return null;
        }
        // Extract the element type. If it's raw, we assume java.lang.Object is in the play
        final Type elementType = getTypeParameter0(typeToken.getType());
        // Get the element type adapter
        final TypeAdapter<?> elementTypeAdapter = gson.getDelegateAdapter(this, TypeToken.get(elementType));
        // And get rid of wildcards
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        final TypeAdapter<Object> castElementTypeAdapter = (TypeAdapter<Object>) elementTypeAdapter;
        // Instantiating a new iterable type adapter
        final TypeAdapter<Iterable<Object>> iterableTypeAdapter = IterableTypeAdapter.get(castElementTypeAdapter);
        // Cast it cheating javac
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        final TypeAdapter<T> castTypeAdapter = (TypeAdapter<T>) iterableTypeAdapter;
        return castTypeAdapter;
    }

    private static Type getTypeParameter0(final Type type) {
        if ( !(type instanceof ParameterizedType) ) {
            return Object.class;
        }
        final ParameterizedType parameterizedType = (ParameterizedType) type;
        return parameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }

    private static final class IterableTypeAdapter<E>
            extends TypeAdapter<Iterable<E>> {

        private final TypeAdapter<E> elementTypeAdapter;

        private IterableTypeAdapter(final TypeAdapter<E> elementTypeAdapter) {
            this.elementTypeAdapter = elementTypeAdapter;
        }

        private static <E> TypeAdapter<Iterable<E>> get(final TypeAdapter<E> elementTypeAdapter) {
            return new IterableTypeAdapter<>(elementTypeAdapter)
                    .nullSafe(); // We don't need to handle nulls ourselves anymore
        }

        @Override
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        public void write(final JsonWriter jsonWriter, final Iterable<E> elements)
                throws IOException {
            // Emit [
            jsonWriter.beginArray();
            for ( final E e : elements ) {
                // Write each element to the downstream writer
                elementTypeAdapter.write(jsonWriter, e);
            }
            // Emit ]
            jsonWriter.endArray();
        }

        @Override
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        public Iterable<E> read(final JsonReader jsonReader)
                throws IOException {
            jsonReader.beginArray(); // Expect [
            final Collection<E> elements = new ArrayList<>(); // This is probably why there is Iterable support by default
            while ( jsonReader.hasNext() ) {
                final E e = elementTypeAdapter.read(jsonReader); // Read each element
                elements.add(e);
            }
            jsonReader.endArray(); // Expect ]
            return elements;
        }

    }

}
```

```java
private static final class Pack {

    Iterable<String> iterable;
    Collection<String> collection;
    List<String> list;
    Map<String, String> map;

}

private static final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapterFactory(getIterableMyTypeAdapterFactory())
        .create();

public static void main(final String... args) {
    final List<String> fooBar = ImmutableList.of("foo", "bar");
    final Pack pack = new Pack();
    pack.iterable = fooBar;
    pack.collection = fooBar;
    pack.list = fooBar;
    pack.map = ImmutableMap.of("foo", "bar");
    gson.toJson(pack, System.out);
}
```

Output before:

```
{"iterable":{},"collection":["foo","bar"],"list":["foo","bar"],"map":{"foo":"bar"}}
```

Output after:

```
{"iterable":["foo","bar"],"collection":["foo","bar"],"list":["foo","bar"],"map":{"foo":"bar"}}
```